# Execution Order of Event Functions in unity3D

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I'm  new to Unity3d,So any one please explain about Execution Order of Event Functions in unity3D

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Answer (score 2):

Awake() is fired immediately upon creation of the (MonoBehavior derived) object during runtime.

Start() is fired at the beginning of each frame once for every new object.

Update() is fired every frame for every enabled object.

LateUpdate() (if enabled) is fired on every object every frame after all objects have completed Update()

FixedUpdate() is fired every time the physics engine reevaluates the RigidBodies - this setting can be adjusted under Project Settings or something like that I don't remember.

There's a bunch of event functions - but those are the main ones and when they fire.

You should probably ask this question on Unity Forums or https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ however as you're more likely to get an answer and not annoy the programmers.